# How do I use selectize.js?

Tags: 8

I create advanced search with views and I want use selectize.js (https://www.drupal.org/project/selectize) for entity refrence selector . How can I do it ?

Comment: How are you creating this advanced search? To use selectize, you need change the render element for desired field, in other words, you need do some backend code.

Comment: I create it with views and use FILTER CRITERIA expose .